# How to get data from Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I' currently learning AJAX technology.

In Chrome console when I type `jsonObject.responseText`, I get all data in the console, but when I do the same in my `.js` file to print that to the console (or HTML element) it says `"undefined"` in the console.

JSON object is from:

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
```

Code in JavaScript:

```
var jsonObject = $.ajax({
url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
dataType: "json"
});
console.log(jsonObject.responseText);
```

Comment: AJAX is, as per its own definition, **asynchronous** in nature. You should check for the resolution of the promise returned by `jsonObject`., i.e. `jsonObject.done(function(response) {...});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

AJAX - **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML.
Which means the data is fetched asynchronously in a separate thread.

```
var jsonObject = $.ajax({ url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", dataType: "json" });

console.log(jsonObject.responseText);
```

your console.log is executed before the $.ajax is actually completed getting data. Thus jsonObject is undefined. By the time you execute same in console $.ajax is complete and now at this point the data is present inside jsonObject unlike before.

You will need to provide a success callback which executes when the response is returned.

```
var jsonObject = $.ajax({ 
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", 
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should access the response you are getting from the ajax call inside the `success` /`done` handler of the call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
    dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function(jsonObject){
       // Received response from the call. Now you can safely access it
       console.log(jsonObject);
   });
```

Here is a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jucugeyixe/edit?html,js,console,output)

Callbacks specified in the `done` handler will be executed when the ajax call successfully receives a response from the server.

Comment: `jqXHR.success()` has been deprecated since jQuery v1.8. Use `jqXHR.done()` instead.

Comment: and The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are **removed as of jQuery 3.0**. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.